# Android gradle sync failed - LOC

Tags: android

So I'm getting this error, any idea where it's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310474/hibernate-commons-annotations-4-0-1-final-jar-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature

Answer (score 0):

Close android studio and delete everything in this folder:

> C:\Users\Your_Username\.gradle

Afterwards Click Sync Project With Gradle Files and then it will work.