# Eclipse with Maven plugin does not work with latest revisions, but works with older ones

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, aspectj, revision

I have a simple project that uses *Spring AOP*. It uses annotation from *AspectJ*. The project is in Maven and it compiles ok with `aspectjtools-1.7.4`. With `aspectjtools-1.8.9` it fails to see accept annotation `@Aspect` imported from `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect`. The same project gives no problems with Gradle and same JARs.

Why would my code not work with latest revision of AspectJ, but works ok with older one?

I am attaching *pom.xml*:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjproblem</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>aspectjproblem</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>

            <!-- WITH 1.8.9: FAILS to see org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect  -->
            <!-- <version>1.8.9</version> -->

            <!-- WITH 1.7.4: SEES OK: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect  --> 
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>        
        </dependencies>
      </project>
```

I guess it must have something to do with compliance-levels or similar things. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Would you mind posting the error message you see? "Does not work" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to understand what was the issue. I tried moving to Java8 and I played with dependencies. The problem I had was:

**- Invalid LOC header (bad signature)**

What means I guess Maven downloaded a corrupted file. I deleted it from repo (e.g. C:\Users\$USER.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjtools ), updated maven and all started working again.