# AndroidStudio -------- Error:Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: android

I have imported a android project to my AndroidStudio.
When I select Sync Project With Gradle Files，it is reporting **Error:Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWUYL.png)

The log like this：

```
2017/3/30
15:37   Gradle sync started

15:37   Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

What should I do？

Comment: Hasn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310474/hibernate-commons-annotations-4-0-1-final-jar-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature) question resolved your issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310474/hibernate-commons-annotations-4-0-1-final-jar-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature)

Answer (score 2):

Press `Ctrl + H` in yours Home directory, then remove `.gradle` folder.

After this `Run` Android Studio.

Comment: By `Home directory`, which directory you are pointing to? The 1 inside the project or the 1 inside the `AppData`.